# Hi! i need help i want to Migration my Apps on websphere to JBOSS error i get this error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, websphere

I keep getting these two errors, any sugestions?

```
 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/@CONTEXT_ROOT@]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBWEB000289: Servlet action threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack from [Module "org.apache.commons.digester:main" from local module loader @ed17bee (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: C:\tools\EAP-6.4.0\modules,C:\tools\EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\.overlays\layer-base-jboss-eap-6.4.13.CP,C:\tools\EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base))]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
```

and

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/@CONTEXT_ROOT@]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBWEB000289: Servlet ApplicationInit threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap from [Module "deployment.WEBCMU_DIM_EAR.ear.commons-beanutils.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
```

Comment: Well, it looks like Apache Commons Collections isn't available in your JBoss, but it's needed.

Comment: yes I have it yet and the build path is well defined; I do not know if it does not need a specific version; org.apache.commons.collections contain .ArrayStack normaly?!

Comment: It's not just ArrayStack, it's also FastHashMap. Thus, it doesn't seem to be finding Collections at all.